# Bringing RDP based connection to an Angular Component with full support on intractability on WebApp side

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, angular

I have been continuously looking out for a solution or similar-way approached problem but in vain.
SO also had similar questions but even they are yet not answered correctly (please bear with me as this is my first question here).
I thus am asking for any kind of help or guidance in this problem:
Need to integrate an RDP-based connection into Angular WebApp as an Angular component in such a way as to retain its full support on interactability and as well as other components/parts of the WebApp.

Any kind of suggestions on reframing the question or editing is whole-heartedly welcomed :)